# ШАБЛОНЫ. MS VS отказывается компилировать программу, непонятная ошибка C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 template <typename T>
 T max5(const T(&)[5]);

 int main() {
     double arr1[] { 2.5, 32.321, -442.4, 41.321, 34.005 };
    int arr2[]{ 3, 45, 0, 412, -32};
    cout << max5(arr1);
    cout << max5(arr2);
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
template <typename T>
T max5(const T (&arr)[5]) {
    T thebiggest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        arr[i] > thebiggest ? thebiggest = arr[i] : continue;

   return thebiggest;
}
```

Вот что пишет : 
error C2760: синтаксическая ошибка: ожидался токен "<Нет данных>, а не "<Нет данных>"
note: Сообщение диагностики возникло в созданной компилятором функции "T max5(const T (&)[5])"
функция должна принимать массив из 5 элементов базового типа и возвращать наибольший.

Comment: Синтаксис бессмыслен. Потому код и не компилируется. Что делает `continue` внутри оператора `?:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, вы имели в виду

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T max5(const T(&arr)[5]) 
{
    T thebiggest = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
        if (arr[i] > thebiggest) thebiggest = arr[i];

    return thebiggest;
}


int main() {
    double arr1[]{ 2.5, 32.321, -442.4, 41.321, 34.005 };
    int arr2[]{ 3, 45, 0, 412, -32 };
    cout << max5(arr1) << endl;
    cout << max5(arr2) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Ну вот например, к чему у вас `continue`? Что такое `i` в теле шаблона? тернарный оператор сравнивает что-то не пойми с чем, и потом пытается выполнять совершенно разные действия (а не выражения одного типа).

Вобщем, простите, но у вас написано такое, что встает один вопрос - зачем программировать, накурившись? :)

Comment: Извините, я скопировал не тот код, одну секунду

Comment: и да, спасибо, ваш код заработал. сейчас запущу отладчик и буду наблюдать, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: извините, а не могли бы вы подсказать,  что же всё-таки не так в моём коде(в изменённой версии)?

Comment: Ветви тернарного оператора должны быть, грубо говоря, однотипны. А у вас одна ветвь имеет некоторое значение, вторая - нет. С учетом приоритетов, кстати, вы сравниваете `arr[i]` с результатом тернарного оператора `thebiggest ? thebiggest = arr[i] : continue` - ну и как, оно больше `continue` или меньше? :) Да и логика хромает: если все значения в массиве меньше 0, то вы считаете, что наибольшее - ноль?

Comment: @Harry, что-то не то про приоритеты. У сравнения приоритет выше, потом тернарник, а у равно ниже, но поскольку он запихнут в среднюю часть, то ему без вариантов.

Comment: @Qwertiy Гм, вообще-то да :( "Ну, тут промашка - переборщили..." (с)

Answer (score 2):

Отвечено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918203/return-statement-in-ternary-operator-c): второй и третий аргументы "тройственного оператора" — выражения, а не операторы (expressions, not statements).